# How to skip an edit form after uploading a single document in SP 2010

Tags: document-library

I would like to set all document properties programmatically inside the event handler. I do not manage to skip an edit form after the document is uploaded. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/04/30/editformaspx-not-shown-when-uploading-a-document/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript solution for `SharePoint 2013`

In `SP.UI.Dialog`, there is a function to close a dialog : `commonModalDialogClose`

Takes two parameters, `commonModalDialogClose(dialogResult, returnValue)`

dialogResult is an enum (here is an extract from `SP.UI.Dialog.js` :

```
SP.UI.DialogResult.prototype = {
    invalid: -1,
    cancel: 0,
    OK: 1
};
```

**Solution** : When using the upload.aspx page, you will be redirected to the `EditForm.aspx` including a `QueryString` parameter, `Mode`, that will be tagged as `Upload`. Using that information, the dialog can be closed. The QueryString parameter is retrieved using the `GetUrlKeyValue` SharePoint native function.

`GetUrlKeyValue(keyName, bNoDecode, url, bCaseInsensitive)`

add the following into the library `EditForm.aspx` using JSLink

```
(function (){
    var mode = GetUrlKeyValue("Mode", false, window.location.href, true);

    if (mode == "Upload")
    {
        //commonModalDialogClose(dialogresult, resultValue)
        //dialog result : -1 = invalid; 0 = cancel; 1 = ok
        //resultValue : text
        commonModalDialogClose(0, null);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi @JayHell, I'm new in Sharepoint, and i find your solution te be a good one, however i don't know where and how to add this `Javascript` code, and what is `JSLink` ?.

I have a `Custom Edit form` which include some new columns i created. and i want to know how to apply this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a matter of at which point in the event handling the document properties should or can be updated. This post explains the various Events and their variations ('-ing', '-ed', etc) - not all properties are available during the synch/asynch event handling - [Managing ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated Events..](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/)

An alternative, is to use PowerShell for document upload. Paul Childs has a PowerShell example that can provide a solution - [Bulk upload files with metadata into SharePoint using PowerShell: UPDATE](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/bulk-upload-files-with-metadata-into.html)